# Assigning value to form using .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

While going through some 3rd party code I realised that they are assigning a value to the form using .val() and then submitting the form.

```
$('#form-ID').val("Some Value");
```

This is a valid jquery statement and if you do

```
$('#form-ID').val()
```

you get `"Some Value"` on the console but no HTML change is observed to reflect the "Some Value". So if there is no HTML change then:

1. Why assign a value to the form ?
2. If it is required how will the PHP code read this value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code works because even though [`HTMLFormElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmlformelement) instances aren't defined to have a `value` property, `val` doesn't check, it just happily assigns to it, creating an expando. This works with any element:

```
var d = $("<div>");
d.val("foo");
console.log(d.val());    // "foo"
console.log(d[0].value); // "foo"
```

Submitting a form with a `value` expando won't include that value with the submission (you can [try it here](http://jsbin.com/javaqopi/1)), so I'd expect if the code is doing this, it's doing it purely for client-side reasons. Or, of course, it's a bug they've never caught and fixed. (Or they might monkey-patch `val` and make it do something special.)